# How to convert an integer to a string in Erlang?

Tags: string, erlang

I know strings in Erlang can be costly to use. So how do I convert `"5"`to `5`?

Is there anything like `io:format("~p",[5])` that would return a formatted string instead of printing to a stream?

Comment: Avoided at all costs?  Where did you get that idea?  There are some performance concerns and other annoyances, but they are still a core data type and the default choice for strings.

Comment: I speak with tongue in cheek.  If I firmly believed that you should never use them, I wouldn't have asked this question.
On the other hand, describing them as a "core data type" might be stretching things a little far, in my view.

Comment: string in erlang is a list. it is core data type. the same as binary or atom.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The following is probably not the neatest way, but it works:

```
1> lists:flatten(io_lib:format("~p", [35365])).
"35365"
```

EDIT: I've found that the following function comes in useful:

```
%% string_format/2
%% Like io:format except it returns the evaluated string rather than write
%% it to standard output.
%% Parameters:
%%   1. format string similar to that used by io:format.
%%   2. list of values to supply to format string.
%% Returns:
%%   Formatted string.
string_format(Pattern, Values) ->
    lists:flatten(io_lib:format(Pattern, Values)).
```

**EDIT 2** (in response to comments): the above function came from a small program I wrote a while back to learn Erlang.  I was looking for a string-formatting function and found the behaviour of `io_lib:format/2` within `erl` counter-intuitive, for example:

```
1> io_lib:format("2 + 2 = ~p", [2+2]).
[50,32,43,32,50,32,61,32,"4"]
```

At the time, I was unaware of the 'auto-flattening' behaviour of output devices mentioned by @archaelus and so concluded that the above behaviour wasn't what I wanted.

This evening, I went back to this program and replaced calls to the `string_format` function above with `io_lib:format`.  The only problems this caused were a few EUnit tests that failed because they were expecting a flattened string.  These were easily fixed.

I agree with @gleber and @womble that using this function is overkill for converting an integer to a string.  If that's all you need, use `integer_to_list/1`. KISS!

Comment: There is absolutely no need to use `io_lib:format/2` for this simple task. `integer_to_list/1` is enough.

Comment: Also, flattening the resulting iolist is normally wasteful. Sockets/Ports/Files/IoDevices all flatten on output, so flattening yourself is redundant.

Comment: integer_to_list/1 is enough for the headlined question, but this does neatly answer my "can you produce formatted strings with interpolated numbers" subquestion...

Comment: It's a pity that this is the selected answer because [womble](http://stackoverflow.com/a/588248/191191)'s is the proper answer.

Answer (score 157):

There's also `integer_to_list/1`, which does exactly what you want, without the ugliness.

Comment: I think you mean list_to_integer/1 and list_to_float/1 as he's trying to go from a string to a number.

Also the documentation for these functions is 'hard to find' as they are both part of the Erlang module and you need to know to look there.

Comment: He's trying to convert 5 to "5". Thus, integer to string.

Comment: strings ARE lists in erlang

Answer (score 32):

A string is a list:

```
9> integer_to_list(123).  
"123"
```

Answer (score 4):

As an aside if you ever need to deal with the string representation of floats you should look at the [work](http://bob.pythonmac.org/archives/2007/12/17/printing-floats-with-erlang/) that Bob Ippolito has done on [mochinum](http://mochiweb.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/mochinum.erl).

Answer (score 2):

lists:concat([Number]). also works.