# String template with erlang

Tags: erlang

With language like JS it's really easy to write something like:

```
var a = 5;
console.log(a + ' times\n');
```

how can I write the same code with erlang?

Comment: possible duplicate of [convert an integer to a string in Erlang](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588003/convert-an-integer-to-a-string-in-erlang)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your question is about stringification of any Erlang term, there is `~p` in `io:format/2,3` function.

```
A = 5, io:format("~p times~n", [A]).
```

If you are interested in *debugging* output, there is also `erlang:display/1` function. It works like `io:format("~p~n", [X]), true.`.